# Inserting multiple rows into a table with a 2 column index ignoring duplicates without query failing

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a relation table with 3 columns

### formsFields

```
[formID] [int] NOT NULL,
[fieldGUID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[position] [int] NOT NULL
```

`formID` and `fieldGUID` columns have a unique constraint in Indexes/Keys.

Currently I'm inserting all of the relations at the same time like:

```
INSERT INTO formsFields(formID, fieldGUID, position)
VALUES 
(1, '{52E9A16E-B489-4577-955F-05749AB0481B}', 0),
(1, '{52E9A16E-B489-4577-955F-05749AB0481B}', 1), 
....
```

With the unique constraint the database wont allow duplicates but the query will fail if any of the rows I'm inserting are duplicate.

Is their a way to run an insert like this and ignore the duplicates? Maybe even inserting into a temp table the merging it into the real table? Need a little help writing a query for this.

Comment: How about an [`INSTEAD OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx) trigger that disregards the duplicates? I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server. It helps to tag SQL questions with the version of the DB being used, e.g. `sql-server-2008`.

Comment: Insert into a temp and then select [formID], [fieldGUID], max[position] from #temp group by [formID], [fieldGUID]

Comment: If there are two records in your set with the same key values, does it matter which gets inserted and which gets ignored?

Comment: Use CTE in which remove duplicates and then insert into table. However, your sample code is seemed to be not adjust to your sample data - `fields` table instead of `formsFields` and with different structure - hard to write correct answer for your question.

Comment: Trying to avoid using triggers. I had a few options create a staging table then insert, execute single insert statements for each row, use a merge statement, or in our case we just deleted all the rows and then reinserted them. I believe you could also turn the ignore duplicates flag on for the table as well. Also sorry for the inconsistency in the code, I'll edit it.

Comment: Regarding the various proposed solutions: There is a bit of work left to do if you want this to work correctly with transactions. If there could be more than one user or application inserting data at one time then you should be concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of using a temporary table, aggregates, and merge.  I'm making the assumption that you want the max position value to be saved.

Now looking at this you might think that you can skip the temp table and just use `values` as the source in the `merge`.  While you can use the values as a source, `on` can only have 0 or 1 matches, multiple rows will result in an error message.

You might think I'm being fancy with the indexes, but they'll speed up the aggregate and the join.  Skip them if performance isn't an issue or space is a concern.

You can remove `AND ff.position < source.pos` from `MATCHED` if you don't think that the position already in the table will ever be higher than the values you are insterting, or if you don't care if you end up with lower positions.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#formsFields2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #formsFields2
END

CREATE TABLE #formsFields2 (
[formID] [int] NOT NULL,
[fieldGUID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[position] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #formsFields2_IX_position
    ON #formsFields2([position])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #formsFields2_IX_ids
    ON #formsFields2([formID], [fieldGUID])

INSERT INTO #formsFields2(formID, fieldGUID, position)
VALUES 
(1, '{52E9A16E-B489-4577-955F-05749AB0481B}', 1),
(1, '{52E9A16E-B489-4577-955F-05749AB0481B}', 2)

MERGE formsFields AS ff
USING (
    SELECT formID, fieldGUID, MAX(position)
    FROM #formsFields2
    GROUP BY formID, fieldGUID
) AS source (formID, fieldGUID, pos)
ON (ff.formID = source.formID AND ff.fieldGUID = source.fieldGUID)
WHEN MATCHED AND ff.position < source.pos THEN UPDATE SET ff.Position = source.pos
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (formID, fieldGUID, pos);
```